# Preventing multiple logins to a website in Play framework

Tags: java, javascript, playframework

I'm working on the design of a program using Play framework for Java. It's a website that requires users to log in and it needs to prevent a user from logging into an account that is already logged in.

When a user logs in, the username is stored in the Cache (using memcached). When the user logs out, the username is disacarded from the Cache. If a login attempt is made for a username that exists in the Cache, the login attempt is rejected.

For example, a user logs in with the username "joe". Someone from another computer attempts to log in with the username "joe" and it gets rejected because "joe" is already logged in.

Simple enough, except when a user closes their browser tab, then they are locked out because their username still exists in the Cache.

So, using javascript, I've captured the window.onbeforeunload event to redirect to a route that runs a Java method that clears the Cache. The problem is that window.onbeforeunload is fired when the user clicks a link or reloads the page. So, if the user reloads the page, they are logged out, or if they click on a link within the website, they are logged out. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

**Edit**:
I am using Security.Authenticated to ensure people can't access the website unless they have a session in their cookie. I have a BaseController that extends Controller and all of my controllers extend BaseController (except the one that handles the login page), and the BaseController is annotated with:

```
@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
```

Secured ensures that when somebody tries to access the website, if they don't have a session, they are redirected to the login page. Once they log in, a cookie is created with the session and Secured will allow them to access the page.

Comment: Why not just put a TTL on the cache entry and update it every time the user has any sort of action?

Answer (score 0):

What about expires time in the cache? And to prevent a key be deleted, even if the user is still active, you can create a composed action that refreshes the cache in every new request.

Alberto

Comment: I've added an edit to the original post with more information. If i create a TTL on the cache then this scenario could occur: 1. User accesses login page 2. User passes authentication and is directed to the landing page 3. User closes their browser, thus deleting their cookie with the session 4. User re-opens their browser and tries to access the website URL directly 5. There is no cookie, so they are redirected to the login page 6. User can't log in because their Cache still exists because the TTL hasn't expired yet

Comment: When the browser closes and deletes the session cookie, is there a way to have it run a javascript function at that time in order to clear the Cache?

Comment: When you close the browser, cookies are not deleted :).

Comment: If you don't put a timeout on a cookie, it's not deleted when the browser is closed?

Comment: No... at least I don't think so.